# Grid line with date and time data in x axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a line graph of the location of Tropical cyclone with time on a 6 hourly basis. I successfully plot the graph with all the needed labels except the gridline both the major and the minor gridlines. The major gridline appears in a 12 hours interval instead of 6 hours. My goal is to put the start of the major grid line at 0 and not a few mm east of 0 in the x-axis. Another thing, I cannot put a minor grid line just at the center between the two major gridlines to represent 6 hourly data or create a 6 hours interval major gridline.

The image below shows the result of my code.
[image]

And this is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (AutoMinorLocator, MultipleLocator)
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, MonthLocator, YearLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.time,df.Distance, color='r',marker = 'o', linestyle ='--')

ax.set_xlabel('Date and Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Distance (km)')
ax.set_title('The expected distance of Tropical cyclone')
plt.grid(True)
ax.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='major',axis ='y', linewidth='1', color='black')
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
ax.tick_params(which='both', # Options for both major and minor ticks
                top='off', # turn off top ticks
                left='off', # turn off left ticks
                right='off',  # turn off right ticks
                bottom='off') # turn off bottom ticks
hloc = HourLocator(1)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hloc)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(50))
m = np.arange(0,round(max(df.Distance+200),100),100)
ax.set_yticks(m)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.ylim(0,1500)
plt.show()
```

and my data for the x-axis is this-

```
0    2019-09-24 04:00:00
1    2019-09-24 10:00:00
2    2019-09-24 16:00:00
3    2019-09-24 22:00:00
4    2019-09-25 04:00:00
5    2019-09-25 10:00:00
6    2019-09-25 16:00:00
7    2019-09-25 22:00:00
8    2019-09-26 04:00:00
9    2019-09-26 10:00:00
10   2019-09-26 16:00:00
11   2019-09-26 22:00:00
12   2019-09-27 04:00:00
13   2019-09-27 10:00:00
14   2019-09-27 16:00:00
15   2019-09-27 22:00:00
16   2019-09-28 04:00:00
```

and the y-axis

```
0     1385
1     1315
2     1245
3     1175
4     1105
5     1050
6      995
7      935
8      880
9      835
10     790
11     745
12     485
13     435
14     390
15     350
16     315
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revised to 6 hour intervals. I wasn't sure of the intent of the grid, so I posted the details and no grid.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (AutoMinorLocator, MultipleLocator)
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, MonthLocator, YearLocator
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,12))

ax.plot(df.time,df.Distance, color='r',marker = 'o', linestyle ='--')

ax.set_xlabel('Date and Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Distance (km)')
ax.set_title('The expected distance of Tropical cyclone')
plt.grid(True)
ax.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='major',axis ='y', linewidth='1', color='black')
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
ax.tick_params(which='both', # Options for both major and minor ticks
 top='off', # turn off top ticks
 left='off', # turn off left ticks
 right='off',  # turn off right ticks
 bottom='off') # turn off bottom ticks
# hloc = HourLocator(1)
# ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hloc)
# ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(50))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(HourLocator(byhour=None, interval=3, tz=None))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator(byhour=None, interval=6, tz=None))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m-%d %H"))

m = np.arange(0,round(max(df.Distance+200),100),100)
ax.set_yticks(m)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.ylim(0,1500)
plt.xlim(df['time'].min(), df['time'].max())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: One (1) minor gridline is missing. The minor gridline should be 5 lines instead of 4 since the time is 5 hourly.

Comment: This one works. ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(HourLocator(byhour=None, interval=1, tz=None))

Answer (score 1):

To view the minor gridlines, you should run

```
plt.minorticks_on()
```

To limit the x-axis of the chart, do:

```
plt.xlim(df.time.min(), df.time.max())
```

The result is below. As you can see, there's a major x-gridline every 6 hours and a minor one every hour.

[image]

Comment: There is a missing 1 minor gridline. The minor gridline should be 5 lines instead of 4.